# Can you explain this proof about the closure of a set?

Tags: general-topology

The author of my textbook has an unsatisfactory proof when it is describing the properties of the closure of a set.
I'm using $E^*$ for E closure. Also, $E'$ indicates the set of limit points of $E$.

> **Theorem:** $E^*\subset F$ for every closed set $F\subset X$ such that $E\subset F$
>
> *Proof*: If $F$ is closed and $E\subset F$, then $F'\subset F$, hence $E'\subset F$. Thus $E^*\subset F$.

My question is, why is he able to conclude that $F$ contains $E$'? Why is $E'$ a subset of $F'$?

Comment: how is defined the closure there? there are many ways

Comment: The closure of E is defined here as $E\intersection E'$

Answer (score 1):

The main implication we will use when proving this theorem is that:

If $E\subset F $ then $ E^* \subset F^*$.

*Proof:* take $x \in E^*$, then for every neigborhood $V$ of $x$, there is a point $y \in E$ such that $y \in V$ as well. But we have that $E \subset F$, so $y \in F$ and $y \in V$. From this, we conclude that $x \in F^*$ and we have the result.

The other fact we will use in proving the main result is that $F$ is closed if and only if $F=F^*$.

Now let's prove the result:

*Proof:* Suppose that $E \subset F$ and $F$ is closed, thus by the previous result, we have that $E^* \subset F^* = F$. And we have the result.

Comment: Why is there a $y\in V$ for any V of x?

Comment: Wouldn't that only be true if $E=E'$?

Answer (score 0):

for your 2nd ques prove if F contains E then F' contains E' if E'=null set then there nothing to prove . Let E' is not a null set then x*e*E' implies x is a limit point of the set E in X implies E meet [B(x,r){x}] is not equal to null set for all +ve real r                                             implies F meet[B(x,r){x}] is not equal to null set as F contains E         implies x is a limit point of F in X                                       implies x belongs to F'  therefore F' contains E'